# Canonical question on updating matrix inverses and factorizations

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

The question "given the inverse/a certain factorization of $A$, can I compute cheaply one of $A+B$?" is one that gets asked a lot here, in slightly different forms: for instance when $A$ is symmetric, or $B$ diagonal (and I have seen it pop up several times on MO as well). The answer is always "no, unless $B$ has small rank (and then you can use SMW or QR/Cholesky updates) or small norm (and then you can use a perturbation approach and/or use $A$ as a preconditioner in an iterative algorithm).

I think it would be useful to have a canonical question in which we explain this in full generality, so that we can refer people to it instead of re-explaining the same thing continuously. What is your opinion? I volunteer to write one in the next days, if you wish.

Comment: Over at Math.SE we settled on a notion of "abstract duplicates".  See the [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) at Meta Math.SE for an illustration of how existing Questions and Answers, often with some editing, can be harnessed.

Comment: I like the approach that @hardmath proposed.

Comment: @hardmath I read your link but I don't really understand --- what is the difference between the concept of canonical question (as used across the whole SE network, see e.g. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) [2](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/what-is-a-canonical-question-exactly) [3](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7115/what-is-a-canonical-answer)) and this "abstract duplicate" thing that they have at math.se? Is it just the same thing with a different name?

Comment: I have decided to ask this also on meta.math.se, since it seems a natural question to me: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29339

Comment: @FedericoPoloni and that thread convinced me now that there is no clear answer to the difference between them...

Answer (score 2):

List of possible candidates for closing as abstract duplicates/canonical questions (for the matrix-inverse/factorization update):

- [Cholesky factorization of a block matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/21066/20688)